# How to create a ListLinePlot with a layout analogous to ChartLayout -> "Stacked"?

Tags: plotting, dynamic

I am using 3 checkboxes as desktops, portables and ipods in such a way that when I click to desktops it should shows `ListLinePlot` of `p1`, when I click to portables, it should show `ListLinePlot` of `p2` and in the same way, when I click to ipods, it shows `ListLinePlot` of `p3`.

```
p1 = {.955, .914, .956, 1.516, 1.355}; 
p2 = {1.462, 1.357, 1.577, 1.917, 2.054};
p3 = {0,0, 1.57, 1.619, 3.997};

Column[{CheckboxBar[
   Dynamic[z], {ListLinePlot[p1, Filling -> Axis, 
      FillingStyle -> Blue] -> Desktop, 
    ListLinePlot[p2, Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> LightBlue] -> 
     Portables, 
    ListLinePlot[p3, Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Green] -> Ipods}], Spacer[5], Dynamic[z]}]
```

This is working correctly. But I want when I click both desktops and portables on, it should show the plots of `p1` and `p2` in a stacked way. Here I am explaining it with the help of `BarChart` because I have no idea whether `ListLinePlot`can do this .

```
BarChart[Table[{p1[[i]], p2[[i]]}, {i, 1, 5, 1}], ChartLayout -> "Stacked"]
```

If I click Desktops, Portables and ipods, then
it should dynamically take data of p1, p2 and p3 in stacked order as

```
BarChart[Table[{p1[[i]],p2[[i]], p3[[i]]}, {i, 1, 5, 1}], ChartLayout -> "Stacked"]
```

and so on. But I want stacked `ListLinePlot` and I don't know any function like `ChartLayout` in `BarChart`. I have seen the `Accumulate` function but it does not work as I wanted. For more clarification, just have a look at

http://graphics.thomsonreuters.com/12/01/US_APPLEBREAK0112_VT.html

I want to do as it is, as in the product button of this link. Please help me.

Comment: By "stacked" do you mean that you need the *sum* of datasets shown?

Comment: Jennifer, I have cleaned up and formatted your question.  Please try to do it yourself the next time.

Comment: Yes. By stacked, I meant that first listlineplot should begin from axis (as always) and the other listlineplot should begin from the first listlineplot.

Comment: Ok. Mr. Wizard,  I will do from next time.

Comment: @Jennifer I'm a bit confused here. Both Szabolcs's and Mike's answer are consistent with the link in your question. In all these the lines are connecting data points belonging to the same device. Yet in your comment to Szabolcs's answer you seem to be asking for a graph where the data points belonging to the same year are connected instead which is different from the plot in the link you referred to.

Comment: After viewing the thomson reuters chart and then re-reading that you want a stacked `ListLinePlot` I am also confused. The product chart appears to me to be exactly what Szabolcs and I have provided. Maybe you could hand draw what you exactly want and scan it and paste it into the question.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch: I am sorry and realised that I was wrong. Its working correctly. Thanks for your reply and helping me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe there is a built-in function to do this automatically, so you will need to implement it from scratch.  It's easy, it just takes a little bit of work.

A useful function is `Accumulate`, if your datasets are of equal length.  If they are not, you may want to linearly interpolate them (`Interpolation`) and use `Plot` instead of `ListPlot`.

Another useful tool is the `Filling` option of plotting functions, which you are already familiar with.  Look up its advanced syntax in the documentation.

This implementation is a little clumsy, but it could be a start:

```
Column[{Dynamic@
   ListLinePlot[
    Accumulate[{ConstantArray[0, Length[p1]], If[q1, p1, 0], 
      If[q2, p2, 0], If[q3, p3, 0]}], 
    Filling -> {2 -> {{1}, LightPurple}, 2 -> {{3}, LightOrange}, 
      3 -> {{4}, LightGreen}}, PlotStyle -> Black],
  Grid[{{Labeled[Checkbox@Dynamic[q1], "Desktop"], 
     Labeled[Checkbox@Dynamic[q2], "Portables"], 
     Labeled[Checkbox@Dynamic[q3], "iPods"]}}, Spacings -> 1]
  }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Beaten by both of you.  I surely am "Fastest Gun in the West" no longer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard haven't been on here much in recent weeks. I just stumbled across this at the right time. You are still the fastest gun in the west :)

Comment: @Mike I'm afraid that's not it: I found the question right after it was posted.  It just took me longer than you guys to get a nice working answer.  I'll guard my pride by pretending that the three minutes I took to edit the question made the difference. :o)  (Honestly the reordering nature of `CheckboxBar` was giving me fits.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I gave up on `CheckboxBar` quickly and went with `Checkbox` instead.

Comment: That was wise; I beat it into submission with spaghetti code.

Comment: @Szabolcs:Thanks for replying but this is not what I actually needed.I wanted that when I click to desktops and portables, then it should plot this dataset {{.955,1.462},{.914,1.357},{.956,1.577},{1.516,1.917},{1.355,2.054}}  It should extract each ith element from p1 and p2 where i is from 1 to5.

Comment: @Jennifer `ListLinePlot[{{.955,1.462},{.914,1.357},{.956,1.577},{1.516,1.917},{1.355,2.054}}]` is something completely different from the BarChart you showed.  Can you update your question and clarify, preferably including an image as well?

Comment: @Szabolcs: I have updated my question for more clarification. I have added a link to it and I want to make it for product button shown in the given link. Sorry for late updation.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Thanks for your reply. I am sorry its working as it is, as I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you want `BarChart` but it isn't 100% clear from your question. You might possibly be wanting a cumulative list plot?

```
p = {{.955, .914, .956, 1.516, 1.355}, {1.462, 1.357, 1.577, 1.917, 
    2.054}, {0, 0, 1.57, 1.619, 3.997}};

Column[{
  CheckboxBar[Dynamic[z], {1, 2, 3}],
  Spacer[{0, 20}],
  Dynamic@If[z =!= {},
    BarChart[p[[#]] & /@ Sort[z], ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
     ImageSize -> 400],
    Spacer[0]
    ]
  }]
```

[image]

For a cumulative plot you could do this:

```
    Column[{
      CheckboxBar[Dynamic[z], {1, 2, 3}],
      Spacer[{0, 20}],
      Dynamic@If[z =!= {},
        ListLinePlot[Accumulate[p[[Sort[z]]]], 
 Filling -> Axis,ImageSize -> 400],
        Spacer[0]
        ]
      }]
```

[image]

This can be made prettier but I think it seems to capture what you are after.

Comment: You could use `Accumulate[p[[z]]]` instead of `Transpose[Accumulate /@ Transpose[p[[#]] & /@ z]]`

Comment: @Heike yes you're correct. When I first tried this I hadn't defined `p` correctly so `Accumulate[p[[z]]]` didn't work. But then I fixed `p` and went off on a tangent!

Comment: @Heike: thanks for reply. But this is not what I actually wanted. I have updated my question and added a link to it which will more clarify my question. I wanted to make my code for product button given in the link.

Answer (score 2):

[StackedListPlot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StackedListPlot.html) in versions 11.2+.

```
StackedListPlot[{p1, p2, p3}, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, All}]
```

[image]